# Get PHP project coverage in real time without ending the program running

Tags: php, code-coverage, php-code-coverage

I want to test the coverage of a php web application.
I need to get the coverage in real time while the program is running, like nyc or jacoco.
Instead of getting it when ending the program, or writing it in advance in the program.
I read the documentation of php-code-coverage and it seems that it cannot be implemented. Are there any tools that can achieve it?

Let me repeat my needs: I want to obtain the coverage of a php web application in real time. For example, I manually complete the registration operation, and then obtain the current coverage (through the command line or other methods); then I manually complete the login operation, Get coverage again...

Comment: The term "coverage" is used along with software tests, eg. how much of the code is covered by unit test for example. Unfortunately you seem to use your own definition of the term "coverage"...

Comment: @HonkderHase Thank you for your reply. Yes, I want to use a black box method based on reinforcement learning to test web applications, like the paper "Automatic Web Testing Using Curiosity-Driven Reinforcement Learning". Therefore, I cannot write test cases in advance like unit testing. Instead, I let the algorithm test randomly and obtain coverage in real time.